# Document updating but not saving in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this. My document shows that it is updating but it does not save to the database. Essentially when I save the module document, I want the tier documents to be updated(which is working) and the tier id to be added to the current module document as well(it shows it updates but does not save to the db)

**My Schema**

```
var moduleSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    description: String,
    tier: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Tier'
    }]
})
```

**My Custom Instance Method**

```
moduleSchema.methods.saveInTier = function(tierTitles, cb){

// expects an array of tier names

var self = this;


var updateTier = function(i){ 
    Tier.findOneAndUpdate({title: tierTitles[i]},
    {$addToSet: {modules: self._id}},
    function(err, tier){
        if(err) throw err;

        //self.tier.set(i, tier._id)
        self.tier.addToSet(tier._id)

        console.log("module saved in tier: ", tier.title)

        return self.tier

    })
}


for(var j=0;j<tierTitles.length;j++){
    updateTier(j)
}
}
```

**Creating the document**

```
var module = new Module({
title: "Chat"
})

module.saveInTier(['default','gold'])

module.save(function(err){
if(err){
    if(err.code == '11000'){
        console.log("module already exists")
    } else {
        throw err
    }
}

console.log("module shows its been updated")
console.log("NEW module: ", module)

})
```

**Accessing the DB**

```
Module.find({}, function(err, docs){ 
console.log(docs) // the tier field is not updated in the database
})
```

Comment: The mongodb docs say that "The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array." So your tiers won't be updated if they already exist.

Comment: Yes, im aware of that. The array is empty to begin with. It shows it has updated but when I check the database, it just shows an empty array which the ids being saved